# PLS-00302: component 'SLEEP' must be declared

Tags: oracle

I am getting the error when I use the below command in SQL;

EXEC SYS.DBMS_SESSION.SLEEP(1);

But If I use the DBMS_LOCK then it's working.

EXEC SYS.DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(1);

ref : https://oracle-base.com/articles/18c/dbms_session-sleep-18c

is there something I am missing while using this command ?

Comment: Works for me on `Oracle Database 18c Express Edition Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production`

Comment: Obvious question - what is your Oracle version?

Comment: it's oracle 11g (11.2)

Answer (score 5):

DBMS_LOCK is a privileged routine, ie, there is a lot of power in it, and thus it typically was protected from general use.  The problem is, the very useful SLEEP routine was also then not available.

In 18c, we realised this problem and so replicated the SLEEP routine to DBMS_SESSION which *is* publicly available.  Thus everyone gets to use SLEEP.

Before 18c, you need to grant execute on DBMS_LOCK to those that want it (which is risky), or create a wrapper function and only grant that, eg

```
create or replace
procedure SYS.SLEEP(n number) is
begin
  dbms_lock.sleep(n);
end;

grant execute on sys.sleep to public;
```

Comment: It is not always a solution.

Comment: Would you care to explain?

Comment: I can't choose the version and I am working in 12c. I am executing a process which catch the executions into a log table. I use a SYSDATE variable and to test the procedure I need the SLEEP command. So, The company where I work will remain in 12c, and the only solution I found was:
Execute each statement like: PR_LOG(MY_TABLE, MY_STEP, OK, ERROR, N_ROWS) into a scripts.sql.
Finally I need to use the sleep 5 function in Linux to see the increment.

In my case I cannot do anything with version or grant privileges.

Comment: Yes, but read my answer again. I gave you an 18c solution AND an explicit for solution for all databases *before* 18c.

Comment: Read the question it has not your specification.

Answer (score 0):

Self made procedure. If you dont have the right to set the grant

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure new_sleep(p_nSekunden  number)

is

  dDate  date := sysdate;
begin
 
  dDate := dDate + ( (1/24/3600) * p_nSekunden );

  loop
    
    exit when sysdate > dDate;       
    
  end loop;

end;
```